# how does the recv function works -winsock functions-

Tags: function, winsock

I just want to know how the recv function works , when i use the recv function does it wait until the server/client sends it something just like the accept function or what?

Answer (score 0):

With a blocking socket, yes - see the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121.aspx).